# How to allocate rows to a list in excel

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I wanted to allocate the work to the number of people that can work on the task.

From the left table (raw data), I will input the names of the available workers. Then as a result, right table, the 5 people was then allocated 3 each. The work for each person is determined by the user, *(much better if it will be automatically calculated to be allocated to each person equally, eg. 10 workloads to 5 people = 2 workload each, 100WL to 5P = 20WL each, and so on. hope you get the gist)*

[image]

I am not familiar to excel, the processes and computations that it can do, but I am familiar to VB6 as it seems to be the backend coding of excel, so I will go down the coding path to execute this command. If possible, it will be greatly appreciated if one can provide me a sample in excel, so I can study, edit and tweak it a tad better as I am new(first time) to using VB6 in excel.

Comment: oh. that kinda works. geez. It repeats itself if you selected all the rows in Worker column. Why didn't I think of that. Thanks, that's one way to answer my question, but I still would like to see others approach in this. Something more like a click away to allocate them all.

Comment: I feel like it doesnt need to be the same as the result I am looking for, the important factor is for me to allocate the workloads, if not equally, to the pool of workers. Your first comment actually solves the problem, but for the sake of the question, if you have the VBA solution, I think it would be a much better approach as I will be able to do more things in future perspective, am I right?

Comment: ^probably, but I don't really know how since this will be my first time to code in excel, but I know how to in desktop IDEs VB6 and VB.Net 'For Each Worker in Pool blah blah' - just don't know how to incorporate it in excel rows and columns.. I just need something like a sample draft that I can follow through, then google will do the rest. lol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will do what you need. Enter it in `B2` and fill it down the column:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(C:C)-1)+2)
```

Breaking it down:

```
INDEX(C:C,[row])    -- Return the value at [row] in column C
```

Where `[row]` is:

```
MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(C:C)-1)+2
```

Breaking this down:

```
ROW()-2        -- Current row number in column B - offset to zero-base
COUNTA(C:C)-1  -- Number of workers in column C (-1 removes header)
MOD()          -- Converts B row number into value in range [0 - # of Workers)
+2             -- Offsets [0-workers) to [2-workers+2) to account for positioning in col C
```

If you only want names to appear in column B if there's a task to perform, you can wrap the formula in an `IF`:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)>0,INDEX(C:C,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(C:C)-1)+2),"")
```

Then you can fill this formula down hundreds of rows and names will get added automatically as you add work.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, just to let you know, tried the formula above, but it doesn't add Carl to the workload. Understanding this will take a long time for me as I am busy this week since my grandpa died, but will study this as soon as I'm free. Thank you for the input.

Comment: Should work fine, as long as your data matches what you've shown in your post (i.e., one header row, pool in column C, etc.). I did make one small change to ensure that workers are assigned, round-robin style, in the order listed in the workbook. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/RZdo50u.png) showing my results using the formula shown above.